# What kind of expression to be pass to Elsa Javascript expression evaluator?

Tags: elsa-workflows

I have tried to pass multiple expressions but none of them is working. Below are some expressions:

1. 1==1
2. 8>3
3. 5<6
4. if(8 > 4)

Here some screenshots for reference:

[Javascript Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLOi7.png)

[Javascript Expression Evaluator response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyfQG.png)

Comment: I just tried this myself, but it works. I'd suggest to open a ticket on GitHub and provide repro steps so we can figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The following expressions you listed will work:

1. 1==1
2. 8>3
3. 5<6

The 4th one will fail, since it's an incomplete expression.
If the expressions you mentioned don't work, it might indicate a bug or some other issue.

I tried to reproduce the expression evaluation with success, so something else might be causing the expressions to fail in your instance. If you open a GitHub issue with repro steps using a clean Elsa project setup and any errors you might be seeing, we will be better equipped to try and help.

PS.
The first screenshot shows an expression of `2+2` which you then try to cast to a `boolean`. In JavaScript, I think this would result in a truthy value, but I haven't tried to see what happens when Jint (the JavaScript evaluation library Elsa uses) executes this.

The second screenshot doesn't show the expression you tried.

In any case, I recommend cresting a small console application demonstrating the issue.